# Why am I receiving jquery access in Rails without using any gems or js libraries?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-6, bootstrap-5

I'm working with Rails 6 and Bootstrap 5.
I didn't add jQuery anyhow, but the output of '$' in the browser's console indicates that the obtaining function, i.e. jQuery is operational/working.
So, at first, I was perplexed by this behaviour.

Second, then I included jQuery with

```
yarn add jquery
```

and continues to function normally.

However, I discovered a distinction between the two cases below:

- When I didn't include jQuery anyhow

  - `$('div').length` returned `undefined`
- When I include jQuery

  - `$('div').length` returned 7

Another issue I'd want to mention is that I was getting a function in the response of the '$' command in both cases, as expected. but the functions were not the same.

Please assist me in acquiring this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The `$` function that you get in the console is different in both cases.

When you don't include jQuery on the page, `$` is an alias for `document.querySelector` and is one of the [Console Utilities](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#querySelector-function). Most of these utilities are quite useful during development, e.g. `$0` is the selected element in the DOM inspector. Note that these are available **only in the console window** — calling them in a `<script>` tag won't work.

When you include jQuery, `$` is the jQuery function, whose return value has a `length` property.